# 2 declaration of $_POST not working

Tags: php

I need to use 2 $_POST. Here's the code but it's not working.

```
if($_POST['grade'] == 'G1') && ($_POST['district'] == 'D1')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if(($_POST['grade'] == 'G1') && ($_POST['district'] == 'D1'))` this is correct syntax

Comment: @Nitin No need to wrap inside parenthesis.

Comment: and what if `$_POST` is empty ??  ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try by this

```
if($_POST['grade'] == 'G1' && $_POST['district'] == 'D1'){

    //Both Founded

}else{

    //Not Founded

}
```

Comment: It's still not working.

Comment: @VenesseYoon What does not working mean? Is it throwing an error? have you tried `var_dump($_POST);` to verify weather the data is actually being sent?

Comment: Oh, it's working. Great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you should also check that `$_POST` is not empty before trying to access any key inside

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    if ($_POST['grade'] == 'G1' && $_POST['district'] == 'D1') {
        #condition fulfilled.
    } else {
        print_r($_POST); #debug $_POST and see where you went wrong
        exit;
    }
} else {
    die('POST GLOBAL IS EMPTY');
}
```

Comment: Better try this. Thanks for giving me another idea.

Comment: @VenesseYoon I encourage you to accept this as an answer.

Comment: Better. No problem.